# How prevent Cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks in Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: firebase-security

In my current project some users submitted text like:

`<script>function myFunction() {alert("Hello! I am an alert box!");}</script>`

`<p><b>This text is bold</b></p>`

into my database which was than displayed or executed on the website.

What are common solutions to prevent this kind of text submission into the Firebase Realtime Database?

I already strip HTML code from the text in my JavaScript.

But it seems it would be more secure with Firebase Realtime Database Security Rules...

Comment: Can you show your code that handles the displaying of the content?

Comment: It is a map project made with Leaflet. I think its too much to show here. I can say that everything I have tried in the JavaScript had not prevented some people to modify the functions and write HTML or script code into the database. So I think the problem has to be addressed in the security rules.

Comment: I found the site's URL, I am trying to see what is going on, but if nothing is wrong then I guess yea you have to use some security rules